# Shiny app run well in Rstudio but file not found error shiny-server

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny-server, shiny

I have a problem with my shiny app.The app file structure is like following:

```
/srv/shiny-server/brand/
├── data
│   ├── MDBrand.txt
│   ├── MMBrand.txt
├── helpers.R
├── js
├── server.R
└── ui.R
```

In helpers.R, I write a function.

```
puncDataToFrame <- function(file){
  rawData<- as.data.frame(fread(file, sep = "\t", header = F))
  data <- .....some process....
  return(data)
}
```

In server.R, the path is like that

```
 setwd("/srv/shiny-server/brand")
source("./helpers.R")
file1 <- "./data/MDBrand.txt"
file2 <- "./data/MMBrand.txt"
brandMonthlyUserByDay <- puncDataToFrame(file1)
brandMonthlyUserByMonth <- puncDataToFrame(file2)
```

When I open the server.R in Rstudio and click runApp. Everything works well.But When I run it in the shiny-server, there is always an error like that:

```
 Error in fread(file, sep = "\t", header = F) : 
  file not found: ./data/MDBrand.txt
```

But the file is indeed there. 
BTW: Each txt file is about 30M. I don't know whether the file size have an affect.

And I'm sure the shiny-server configuration is correct. Because I've run some other apps properly in this shiny-server.

Comment: U have  paths in `file1` and `file2` but in code you are using `file`

Comment: @AaghazHussain, I'm sorry that I didn't describe it clearly. In fact, I pass file1 and file2 as a parameter to the function in helpers.R.  I'll update the problem. Thx anyway

Comment: Show us `getwd()` please

Comment: @AndriyT. At first, I didn't write setwd().It didn't work. After that, I add ` setwd("/srv/shiny-server/brand") ` in server.R. It still didn't work

Comment: it is strange that `source("./helpers.R")` works but fread not. Try putting the whole path to a file, make a smaller sample of a file or try with `read.table()`... probably some of this test will indicate you the correct way

Comment: Do you need to set the working directory?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I'm not sure. But I tried both ways. Both don't work

Comment: Try getting the working directory that is set when the script runs. Perhaps have it written down into a txt file.

Comment: @AndriyT. What's more strange is that I run exactly the same app in RStudio, it works really well. But in shiny-server, NO.

Comment: It's not strange, we're just misunderstanding one piece of functionality. Have you tried finding out what the working directory on the server is?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik. Yes, it's `/srv/shiny-server/brand`

Comment: Do you have your files in the server(not on your local machine) ? and did u set the correct path to the files ?

Comment: @Shiva, I have tried both ways, in the server and on local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is happening because of permissioning available to the server (third person/guest) on the folder and file where the file is stored. if you change the guest permission settings on the data folder, it should resolve the issue.

Sarang

Comment: Exactly, problems like "Error: Can't open the connection" or "File not found" are almost caused by the permission issue. Trying to change the permission of the file will solve it.

Comment: How can the file permissions be changed with ubuntu?